# "With X equals 3" vs. "With X equal to 3"

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-structure

I found several teachers using the first structure, i.e. "*with X equals 3*", while some others using the second one, and all of them are native English speakers. Here're some examples of the first structure:

- We'd start with X equals 3. ([source](https://youtu.be/dGd519SL114?si=NtgSujQr091fY-5g&t=2080))
- You've got an atom in the general position 96l with x equals something. ([source](https://youtu.be/Ra9feLehKwA?si=1Kzxf-p2k4MrAZDp&t=48))

My understanding is that the second one is more popular than the first one because "*with + **object***" is often followed by an adjective in form of a gerund verb or past participle.

I've run through the available examples on Longman and Oxford dictionaries and found no instances of the first structure. So for the second structure I think one possible explanation is that "*X equals 3*", as the whole, acting like a noun phrase. Is that explanation valid or are there any other explanations for it?

Comment: "With X equals 3" sounds wrong to me. As you say, "with" takes either a noun phrase or a noun phrase plus a complement. Maybe they're confusing it with "When X equals 3" or something else? Mathematicians aren't always known for their grammar.

Comment: I would say _**with** T **equal to** 35, incidence of heatstroke is H_

Comment: @StuartF, for your reference: here's the one of the videos, https://youtu.be/Ra9feLehKwA?si=lw-N_KUkfKxe-xdI&t=46

Comment: And here's another one, https://youtu.be/dGd519SL114?si=EW8o_aHRdQ4KsMLF&t=2082

Comment: Can you edit the relevant sentences from the videos into your post? The context of the rest of the sentence is likely to affect whether it's grammatical or not.

Comment: @Laurel, I've added.

Answer (score 1):

To my ear, *[with] **X equals 3*** sounds more like the ***result*** of evaluating an equation, rather than setting a variable as a "parameter". That implication is less noticeable in *[with] **X equal to 3***, but I think they're both "sub-standard" compared to...

> ***with X set to 3***

Comment: Or maybe ***where** X equals 3*. This kind of construction is used for instance to complete a definition, as in “Energy and mass are related by the equation *E* = *mc* <sup>2</sup>, where *c* is the velocity of light in a vacuum.”

Comment: Yes, but *usually* if we have ***where** [symbol] equals / **=** [value]* after an actual equation, the "[value]" part is a *verbal description*, rather than a number. "the velocity of light in a vacuum" in your example, not "186,000" (miles per second). And that *can't* be "set to" some different value, since it's a *constant*.

Comment: And in such definition-completion contexts, the fragment following *where* must be a syntactically complete (sub-) sentence.

Comment: I agree about verbal rather than numerical.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, "set" in that case is still in the form of an adjective right?

Comment: Yes, it's a past tense verb used adjectivally. Same as *...with X **initialized** to 3* (another past tense verb modified by ***to 3***), or *...with X **zeroised*** (no adverbial modifier).